# AES encrypt/decrypt with stored key?

Tags: java, sqlite, encryption, aes

I am currently programming a password manager.
The passwords are stored in a database. But now I want to encrypt the passwords in the database. I don't know anything about encryption, but I came across the AES algorithm.

Encrypting/decrypting in a single class with a string works. However, when I want to transfer this to my PW Manager, a new key is generated each time, which is why I can no longer access the stored passwords. So I think I need to store the key somewhere so I can encrypt and decrypt the passwords over and over again, right?
If I am wrong, please correct me :)

My questions now are:

**1. How and where can I store the generated key?**

**2. Does it even make sense to save the key? Or are there better methods for this?**

Comment: Password Managers can be very tricky to implement. I can suggest [this](https://youtu.be/w68BBPDAWr8) video on the subject

Comment: Reinvent the Wheel? There are already opensource password managers like [KeePass](https://keepass.info/)

Comment: @HariKrishnan Thank you, I will have a look at it later :)

Comment: @kelalaka I know, it's a project for school ;)

Comment: It is a good opensource manager so you can read and look at the code, also other mention their way in their pages.

Comment: You could encrypt the key ;). Seriously, you can for instance use a PBKDF to derive a key from a master password, and use that to encrypt your database.